# Separating characters in Bash/sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file like:

```
09/03/2018 t38940 "https:/dsdsadasdsa.dsadsa.dsadsa
09/03/2018 x38940 "https:/dsadas.dsad.dsa
09/03/2018 d38940 "https:/dasdsa.dsadas.dsadsa
09/03/2018 (38940 "https:/dsadas.dsadasd.dsa
09/03/2015 )38940 "https:/dsds.dasdas.d
```

I want to get the result:

```
09/03/2018 38940 "https:/dsdsadasdsa.dsadsa.dsadsa
09/03/2018 38940 "https:/dsadas.dsad.dsa
09/03/2018 38940 "https:/dasdsa.dsadas.dsadsa
09/03/2018 38940 "https:/dsadas.dsadasd.dsa
09/03/2015 38940 "https:/dsds.dasdas.d
```

I want to remove numbers and characters attached to the 2nd column on the beginning (it is always only one character).

How can I write a sed command to get that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your columns are always separated by a single space.

Capture the first column `\([^ ]* \)` (zero or more non-space characters, followed by a space), and ignore the next character `.` (don't include it in the replacement):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]* \)./\1/' file
```

More generally, to do this for the Nth column, then capture N-1 repetitions, e.g.:

```
sed 's/\(\([^ ]* \)\{2\}\)./\1/' file
```

would remove the first character of the 3rd column.

Use `-E` to use `()` and `{}` without backslashes:

```
sed -E 's/(([^ ]* ){2})./\1/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

this sed one-line works for your example:

```
sed 's/ ./ /' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier using awk:

```
awk '{$2=substr($2,2)}1' file
```

This script removes the first character of the second element of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/^\)|^\(/,"",$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do let me know reason for down vote here?/

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly for encouraging one of those *"Givez mez the codez"* questions. I'm kind of surprised someone upvoted the question. There was no effort and it appears to be a requirements dump.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `cut`, assuming you'll always want to remove the 12th character:

```
cut -c 12 --complement infile
```

Or with any POSIX compliant `cut`:

```
cut -c -11,13- infile
```