# Reformat data using awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a dataset that contains rows of UUIDs followed by locations and transaction IDs. The UUIDs are separated by a semi-colon (';') and the transactions are separated by tabs, like the following:

```
01234;LOC_1=ABC    LOC_1=BCD    LOC_2=CDE
56789;LOC_2=DEF    LOC_3=EFG
```

I know all of the location codes in advance. What I want to do is transform this data into a format I can load into SQL/Postgres for analysis, like this:

```
01234;LOC_1=ABC
01234;LOC_1=BCD
01234;LOC_2=CDE
56789;LOC_2=DEF
56789;LOC_3=EFG
```

I'm pretty sure I can do this easily using awk (or similar) by looking up location IDs from a file (ex. LOC_1) and matching any instance of the location ID and printing that out next to the UUID. I haven't been able to get it right yet, and any help is much appreciated!

My locations file is named `location` and my dataset is `data`. Note that I can edit the original file or write the results to a new file, either is fine.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comment on knowing the locations and the mapping file makes me suspicious what your example seems to have done isn't exactly what is being asked - but it seems like you're wanting to reformat each set of tab delimited `LOC=` values into a row with their UUID in front.

If so, this will do the trick:

```
awk ' BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} {split($2,locs,"\t"); for (n in locs) { print $1,locs[n]}}'
```

Given:

```
$ cat -A data.txt
 01234;LOC_1=ABC^ILOC_1=BCD^ILOC_2=CDE$
 56789;LOC_2=DEF^ILOC_3=EFG$
```

Then:

```
$ awk ' BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} {split($2,locs,"\t"); for (n in locs) { print $1,locs[n]}}' data.txt
 01234;LOC_1=ABC
 01234;LOC_1=BCD
 01234;LOC_2=CDE
 56789;LOC_2=DEF
 56789;LOC_3=EFG
```

The `BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"}` block sets the input and output delimiter to ;.

For each row, we then split the second field into an array named locs, splitting on tab, via - `split($2,locs,"\t")`

And then loop through locs printing the UUID and each loc value - `for (n in locs) { print $1,locs[n]}`

Comment: Hopefully you dont care about the order of the output since this will scramble it in a random order. You MAY have got lucky and got the order you expected for your posted sample input but that'd just be luck.

Comment: @EdMorton is correct as usual =). Capturing splits output (e.g. `n=split($2,locs,"\t")`) and modifying the loop to iterate over that - `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { print $1,locs[i]}}`,would give you ordered results if desired.

Comment: It is very discouraging that someone always down vote all the answers to be honest :( there are some people who have to start some time learning coding and look forward to us to help or guide them, so we are trying to do here. I would like to request person(who down votes) to think from their perspective also as we all are here for learning. anyways I got 4 from morning for no reason mentioned :(

Comment: Not "someone" - @jww. I'm upvoting them all as usual now to compensate. Let me know which other questions he's crapped all over lately and I'll go upvote them too.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks Ed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947462/separating-characters-in-bash-sed/50947500#50947500   and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001321/shell-script-to-grep-string-and-its-value-and-produce-output-in-another-file/51001838#51001838 and mostly my day starts with a -ve only I was too discouraged yesterday to be honest.

Comment: Done, all referenced Q&A blindly upvoted to compensate for @jww's blind downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

awk without using `split`: use semicolon *or* tab as the field separator

```
awk -F'[;\t]' -v OFS=';' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1,$i}' file
```

Comment: Yup, it's that simple to do the job robustly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to match against a known list of locations; you should be able to just print each line as you go:

```
$ awk '{print $1; split($1,a,";"); for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) print a[1] ";" $i}' file
01234;LOC_1=ABC
01234;LOC_1=BCD
01234;LOC_2=CDE
56789;LOC_2=DEF
56789;LOC_3=EFG
```

Answer (score 2):

How about without loop or without split one as follows.(considering that Input_file is same as shown samples only)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"\n"$1 OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((.*;)\S+)\s+(\S+)/\1\n\2\3/;P;D' file
```

Repeatedly replace the white space between locations with a newline, followed by the UUID and a `;`, printing/deleting each line as it appears.